# Firebase _upload writes random downloadURL

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage, imagepicker

Below is a simple firebase image uploader. The problem is that it sometimes uses another image's downloadURL as the value when it writes to Firestore. It uploads my image to cloud storage without a problem but then when it goes to write the location to firestore, it often uses the URL of another image. The full code is below but I have omitted the UI. How do I ensure that it writes the correct URL to firestore?

````
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class ImagePicky2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Remove the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  double? lat, lng;
  File? file;
  String? name, detail, pathImage, dateString;

  // Select an image from the gallery or take a picture with the camera
  // Then upload to Firebase Storage
  Future<XFile?> _upload(String inputSource) async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User firebaseUser = auth.currentUser!;
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    try {
      final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(
          source: inputSource == 'camera'
              ? ImageSource.camera
              : ImageSource.gallery,
          imageQuality: 25,
          maxWidth: 1920);

      final String fileName = path.basename(pickedImage!.path);
      File imageFile = File(pickedImage.path);

      try {
        // Uploading the selected image with some custom meta data
        await storage.ref(fileName).putFile(
            imageFile,
            SettableMetadata(customMetadata: {
              'uploaded_by': firebaseUser.displayName!,
              'description': 'Some description...'
            }));

        // Refresh the UI
        setState(() {});
      } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
        print(error);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
    photoUploadFirestoreDetails();
  }

  // Retriew the uploaded images
  // This function is called when the app launches for the first time or when an image is uploaded or deleted
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> _loadImages() async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User firebaseUser = auth.currentUser!;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> files = [];

    final ListResult result = await storage.ref().list();
    final List<Reference> allFiles = result.items;

    await Future.forEach<Reference>(allFiles, (file) async {
      final String fileUrl = await file.getDownloadURL();
      pathImage = await file.getDownloadURL();
      final FullMetadata fileMeta = await file.getMetadata();
      files.add({
        "url": fileUrl,
        "path": file.fullPath,
        "uploaded_by": fileMeta.customMetadata?['uploaded_by'] ?? firebaseUser.displayName,
        "description":
        fileMeta.customMetadata?['description'] ?? 'No description'
      });
    });

    return files;
  }

  Future<Null> photoUploadFirestoreDetails() async {
    Firebase.initializeApp();
    Map<String, dynamic> map = Map();
    map['PathImage'] = pathImage;

    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    CollectionReference collectionReference =
    firestore.collection('MarkerCollect');
    await collectionReference.doc().set(map).then((
        value) {
          });
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is uploading random download urls to Firestore because you're getting the image path from the `_loadImages` method which loads up the files on storage instead of using the download url of the just uploaded file.

This is the problematic code:

```dart
Future<Null> photoUploadFirestoreDetails() async {
  ...
  map['PathImage'] = pathImage;
  ...
}
```

**Solution:**

You can fix this by retrieving the download url just after the upload and passing it to the `photoUploadFirestoreDetails` method to be used in the Firestore upload.

You should also put the `photoUploadFirestoreDetails` in the `try-catch`.

Checkout the updated code below:

```dart
// _upload method

Future<XFile?> _upload(String inputSource) async {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User firebaseUser = auth.currentUser!;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  try {
    final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(
        source: inputSource == 'camera'
            ? ImageSource.camera
            : ImageSource.gallery,
        imageQuality: 25,
        maxWidth: 1920);

    final String fileName = path.basename(pickedImage!.path);
    File imageFile = File(pickedImage.path);

    try {
      // Uploading the selected image with some custom meta data
      final Reference storageReference = storage.ref(fileName);
      await storageReference.putFile(
          imageFile,
          SettableMetadata(customMetadata: {
            'uploaded_by': firebaseUser.displayName!,
            'description': 'Some description...'
          }));
      final String downloadUrl = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();

      // Refresh the UI
      setState(() {});

      await photoUploadFirestoreDetails(downloadUrl: downloadUrl);
    } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    print(err);
  }
}
```

```
// photoUploadFirestoreDetails method

Future<Null> photoUploadFirestoreDetails({@required String downloadUrl}) async {
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  Map<String, dynamic> map = Map();
  map['PathImage'] = downloadUrl;

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  CollectionReference collectionReference =
  firestore.collection('MarkerCollect');
  var value = await collectionReference.doc().set(map);
}
```

Comment: This got it on the first try, I did have to remove the @ from required or add a ? to String, both seemed to make it happy. Thank you so much, you're help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this function to upload image to fire-storage and get Url

```
  Future<String?> uploadAndGetUrl(File file) async {
    try {
      final Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('profilePhoto')
        .child(DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString());
      UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);
      await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
      String url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      return url;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Firebase Storage Error is : $e');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

OR you can just upload an image and get the image URL later.

Your upload image function looks okay. the **name should be unique**. otherwise, it returns a different image url.

```
  Future<String> getUrl(String imageName) async {
    try {
      Reference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('profilePhoto/$logo');
      String url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();

      return url;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```